# Are Salesforce Labs apps managed or unmanaged? Does Salesforce provide support for those?

Tags: appexchange, package, support, salesforce-support

As the title says: are those apps managed or unmanaged packages? Does Salesforce provide support for those or not?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site and visit the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) & [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). Regarding this question, its best that you reach out to Salesforce Labs on their Twitter handle.

Answer (score 2):

If you **read** the description of a Salesforce Labs app on AppExchange, you'll see:

> Salesforce Labs is a program that lets salesforce.com engineers, professional services staff & other employees share AppExchange apps they've created with the customer community. Inspired by employees' work with customers of all sizes and industries, these apps range from simple utilities to entire vertical solutions. **Salesforce Labs apps are free to use, but are not official salesforce.com products**, and should be considered community projects - **these apps are not officially tested or documented**. **For help on any Salesforce Labs app please consult the Salesforce message boards - salesforce.com support is not available for these applications.** Questions? Please visit https://success.salesforce.com/answers.

So: no, Salesforce does not provide support for those apps. And they usually are not managed (personally I have never seen a managed package from Sf Labs before).

Comment: Similar details are also included in Help with Salesforce Labs created applications [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332395&type=1)